# Examples of site navigation that aren't a top or side nav?

Tags: website-design, navigation

I've been making a few websites for classes and I'm wondering if anybody's seen some good examples of websites that do not use a top bar or sidebar for navigation, AND if those websites funciton as effectively as those that do have the nav bars. An explanation as to why that nav scheme works so well would be great as well.

Comment: no top or side nav, that only leaves bottom...i'd like to see example of that too.

Comment: I wasn't necessarily thinking a bottom bar. I've seen some sites that don't use a nav bar at all and just ask users to side swipe/scroll or scroll up and down through pages and sections, I was looking for these kinds of examples. Ones that throw out the bar all together for something totally different.

Comment: There is no correct answer to 'show me some examples of X' questions. Can you rephrase the question so that it can be given a correct answer? Explain the situation you have, why the options you've gone with haven't worked and we can provide a suggested improvement to your situation. Just asking for lists of examples don't constitute answers as there is no such thing as a 'correct' example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I remember back in the 90s, the favourite alternative to Flash was Image Maps.
The trend was to creatively embed navigation into a graphic to create a more immersive experience. The concept of the web was still very abstract so the best way for users to get through a site is to create navigation elements which tied to real world experiences. Skeumorphism was paramount.

Example of Image Map: http://css-tricks.com/examples/ImageMapTooltips/

Due to the rise of usability and modern navigational convention, here we are today clinging to Nav bars because it's easier than reinventing the wheel, especially since it is easier for users to get around and for developers to code.

Mobile has introduced other methods such as burger navigation, and drawers.

Without repeating Sheriff's suggestions above, here are some more inspirational links to browse:

Many design agencies try to avoid conformity (and accessibility it seems) in creative ways. You can see them showcased in Awwwards and
http://www.awwwards.com/websites/design-agencies/

http://www.noupe.com/design/50-interesting-navigation-menus.html

> [image: example]

http://spyrestudios.com/navigating-the-navigation-designs-for-the-innovative/

> [image: example]
>
> [image: example]

I suppose now the trend might go back full circle again just to stand out.

Answer (score 0):

i can't think of any with nav bars at the bottom and i would have high doubts about if they had effective functionality since they are somewhat essential to navigating to other pages, which is a functionality.

some websites provide a sitemap at the bottom though (like this one), allowing the user to still access what was on the nav bar, even though is it not in view. fancily-designed websites, such as http://www.hugeinc.com/, have a navigation overlay though. not sure how to categorize that though.

the bottom nav bar scheme works great for mobile applications due to the ergonomic design and position of the home button (mainly on Android and iOS devices). see instagram for an example of an app with a nav bar at the bottom.

Comment: I wasn't necessarily thinking a bottom bar. I've seen some sites that don't use a nav bar at all and just ask users to side swipe/scroll or scroll up and down through pages and sections, I was looking for these kinds of examples. Ones that throw out the bar all together for something totally different.

Comment: ah. my mistake. well yeah, that can be effective depending on the amount of content to be shown at initial glance. still using the huge website as an example, they provide a hidden/no-menu option, where links within the longer home page can dive into the rest of the website's content via links to subpages. i can see this being most effective for companies, individuals, and things where site content can take a backseat to what they are actually conveying. i don't think it would work so much for e-commerce or social media type sites, where content is priority.

Comment: that's sound reasoning in my opinion. Thanks sheriff, I'll keep this open a little longer incase someone has some really inspirational examples but if by tomorrow or the day after I've got nothing then I'll give you the answer rep.

Comment: it's something i look forward to looking into as well. here's a few more resources to view as well: http://www.noupe.com/design/40-websites-with-unusual-navigation.html, http://www.1stwebdesigner.com/inspiration/creative-website-unusual-navigation/, http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2013/07/11/innovative-navigation-designs/, and a blog post that discusses your question (w/some good comments @ the end): http://www.webdesignerdepot.com/2014/01/3-reasons-we-should-stop-using-navigation-bars/